# Create web API with /path/to/{unique-path}/ design

Tags: php, api, rest, webapi

I am currently learning web development and working on my own small website. I followed a  [tutorial by W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp) and used the learned to create a working login page. It takes the input and sends it using JQuery.

Now I wanted to learn more about how to create an API to manage users and found [a guide on the best practices when designing a REST Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design) by Microsoft. It also contained an example of what a user and order management API system could look like.
In the article they show a similar table looking like this:

| Resource | POST | GET | PUT | DELETE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /users | Create user | Get all users | Bulk update users | Delete all users |
| /users/{id} | Error | Get user Info | Update user details | Delete user |
| /users/{id}/orders | Create order | Get all orders | Bulk update orders | Remove all orders |
| /users/{id}/orders/{id} | Error | Get Order Info | Update order details | Delete order |

How can I implement this into my project and is it possible with just PHP and Javascript?
When searching for it online I only found C# answers

My request for logging in currently looks like this:

```
function login() {
    var username = $("#username-input").val();
    var password = $("#password-input").val();
    $.post("/ajax/account/login.php", 
        {
            username: username,
            password: password
        },
        function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
            data = JSON.parse(get_ajax_response_text(jqXHR))
            if(data.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
                showError("<b>ERROR:</b> " + data["message"]);
            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = "/hub";
                }, 1000)
                showSuccess(data["message"]);
            }
        },
    );
}
```

Thanks for helping in Advance

Comment: I don't know why the formatting is not looking like it is supposed, if you go to edit and look at the preview you should be able to see the table

Comment: Better to read the Fielding dissertation first. https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm For example REST does not have classic login with server side session. It is designed for machine to machine communication between servers or on a single server between applications. Using it for webapplications as backend is just overcomplicating things.

Comment: @inf3rno Ok I thought this was the best step, after having a look at public APIs like Discord or Twitch. 
Is there any improvement I can make then? Here is my login.php code: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/013f73833c4a49afa324b05b505a4bf6

My JSON answer looks something like this:
`{"error":"wrong_login","status":"403","message":"Wrong Username or Password","info":{"user":"brentspine2"}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using [Symfony](https://symfony.com/), which allows me to do exactly what I wanted. They have a great Tutorial on [SymfonyCasts.com](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5) which goes through everything you need to know.

I'm leaving the question open for others to find